# Phone Number Automatically Add When Export To Excel File

Tags: php, excel, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I have **+82-2-573-3585** in my database but when I **export .xls** file using the following codes below the number add automatically so it result to **-4078**. How can I make the phone number in my excel file the same with my database phone number?

```
<?php  
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '');  
    mysqli_select_db($conn, 'databasename');  

    $setSql = "SELECT contact_number FROM supplier";  
    $setRec = mysqli_query($conn, $setSql);  

    $columnHeader = 'SUPPLIERS'; 
    $columnHeader = "Mobile Number" . "\t";  

    $setData = '';  

    while ($rec = mysqli_fetch_row($setRec)) {  
        $rowData = '';  
        foreach ($rec as $value) {  
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";  
            $rowData .= $value;  
        }  
        $setData .= trim($rowData) . "\n";  
    }  


    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");  
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Machine_Supplier.xls");  
    header("Pragma: no-cache");  
    header("Expires: 0");  

    echo ucwords($columnHeader) . "\n" . $setData . "\n";  
?>
```

Comment: Ensure that it's wrapped in quotes, so that it will be treated as a string; if you use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function rather than your faulty homebrew alternative, then it will do this automatically for you

Comment: PS. Your question has nothing whatsoever to do with PHPExcel, which is a PHP library that is written to work with real native-format spreadsheet/excel files

Comment: Sorry about that I just change or remove the tag sir. But in adding qoutes with my phone number using the following codes. How can I do that sir?? @Mark Baker

Comment: My comment provides a [link to the fputcsv() function that PHP provides for writing a csv file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).... read that

Answer (score 0):

Please try this following code.

```
<?php  
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '');  
    mysqli_select_db($conn, 'databasename');  

    $setSql = "SELECT contact_number FROM supplier";  
    $setRec = mysqli_query($conn, $setSql);  

    $columnHeader = 'SUPPLIERS'; 
    $columnHeader = "Mobile Number" . "\t";  

    $setData = '';  

    while ($rec = mysqli_fetch_row($setRec)) {  
        $rowData = '';  
        foreach ($rec as $value) {  
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";  
            $rowData .= strval($value);  
        }  
        $setData .= trim($rowData) . "\n";  
    }  


    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");  
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Machine_Supplier.xls");  
    header("Pragma: no-cache");  
    header("Expires: 0");  

    echo ucwords($columnHeader) . "\n" . $setData . "\n";  
?>
```

Hope it works

Comment: Can you please try your code by removing the **header** functions, so it print all the data normally. So we can understand that the phone number is coming from db or not

Comment: Nothing happen -4074 is the result!! The + sign are converted into = equal sign so it add automatically. @Tristup

Comment: Please check your db value, or you change the **table** field to **char**

Comment: Sorry still -4078. Sorry for a mind-breaking question sir @Tristup .

Comment: If db is storing that data, then problem with the data insertion or field type, as you describe the value **+82-2-573-3585** it should the stored in any **char** field, if it is **integer** please change it to **char** and restore the value, then check.

Comment: I using varchar and not integer at the moment I export the file. And I change it to char base from your recommendation but still nothing change or happen. @Tristup

Comment: It will not change if the value stored in the db is different or already changed. Please check that too

Comment: The following data in the database didn't change and still +82-2-573-3585 even I change the data type from variable character (varchar) to character (char).@Tristup

Comment: Then if you ran the code without **header** functions, is the value changed.?

Comment: I try removing the header then nothing happen. And I think the header affect the data or the  that number.@Tristup

Comment: What do you by Nothing Happen. Is the number printing in a proper manner???

Comment: See I have tried manually the number in excel sheet and found the number -4078. Actually it is taking as **=+82-2-573-3585** so it react as a calculation. If it can be done please remove **+** sign or add a single quote (**'**) at first

Comment: Like this **'+82-2-573-3585** or ** 82-2-573-3585 **

Comment: Still -4078. When I export the file an automactic calculate in excel done I think. That the plus sign (+) in  +82-2-573-3585 was converted to equal sign (=). Yes I agree with you that I can I asterisk or any character before plus sign, the way we need to cheat with it. But I think thats not a proper way of adding phone number because if an end-user ask by a phone number they directly type their number with plus sign without any characters infront. I think we need to look for a solution in exporting not in entering data in a database. @Tristup

Comment: I think you may use any PHP Plugins for Excel like PHPExcel or else, that will help you to fix the type of the column in excel sheet.